# Is there any ways to connect the external database with wordpress elementor and store form data in different pages to different table?

Tags: database, wordpress, elementor

I tried this and was only able to connect to first table for homepage form and was not able to do the same thing in form form different page:\

```
    add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record' , function( $record, $ajax_handler ) { 
        $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );
        if ( 'FORM_ONE' == $form_name )
        {
        $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
        $fields = [];
        foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
        $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
        }
        $wpdb_c = new wpdb( "DB-name", "DB_Pass", "database-name", "localhost"  );
        $output['success'] = $wpdb_c->insert('Tablename', array( 
            'name' => $fields['name'],
            'email' => $fields['email'],
            'message' => $fields['message']));
    
        $ajax_handler->add_response_data( true, $output );
        }
        elseif ( 'FORM_TWO' == $form_name ) {
        $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
        $fields = [];
        foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
        $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
        }
    
        $wpdb_d = new wpdb( "DB-name", "DB_Pass", "database-name", "localhost"  );
        $output['success'] = $wpdb_d->insert('Tablename', array(
            'first_name' => $fields['first_name'], 
            'last_name'  => $fields['last_name'],
            'email1' => $fields['email1'],
            'email2' => $fields['email2'],
            'dob' =>  $fields['dob'],
            'phone_no' => $fields['phone_no'],
            'country' => $fields['country'],
            'gender' =>  $fields['gender'],
            'preference' => $fields['preference'],
            'details' => $fields['details'],
            'where_did_hear' => $fields['where_did_hear'],
            'file' => $fields['file']));
            $ajax_handler->add_response_data( true, $output);
        }
    
        }, 10, 2);
```

I am using backend database as MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using REST API? Connecting external database via rest api such as  Supabase might be solution you are looking for.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."